# Indexing products with boundingPolys

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have a problem with Cloud Vision product search. I did a lot of indexes via CSV, but I can't index with `boundingPolys` column. I got the error
message:

> The number of columns in the csv line should be 8, but the detected
>   number of columns is 1.

I noticed that the error is caused by using quotation marks to any column in CSV file.

Based on example in google tutorial:

The below csv line causes the error:

```
"gs://example-reference-images/10001-001/10001-001_A.jpg","img001","sample-set-summer","sample-product-456","blue summer bag","apparel","style=womens,color=blue","670,790,980,790,980,920,670,920"
```

while, this works fine:

```
gs://example-reference-images/10002-002/10002-002_B.jpg,img002,sample-set-summer,sample-product-123,apparel,,,
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Can you please share the exact csv file that you used? There should not be a problem handling quotes in csv entries.

Comment: I have created  example csv with one item [here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/yoshai-nbrown.appspot.com/o/csv%2Fex.csv?alt=media&token=0b19486c-7c42-4caa-b013-62ef2eea8ae5). 
Without quotation marks and therefore without bounding polys, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV isn't formatted properly. This is what I'm seeing:

"""gs://yoshai-nbrown.appspot.com/images/AA011QM01^0.jpg"",""AA011QM01^0.jpg"",""testset"",""AA011QM01"",""shoe"",""apparel"",""category=shoe"",""0.03,0.24,0.97,0.24,0.97,0.76,0.03,0.76"""

Note all of the extra quotation marks.

Comment: In Microsoft office look like this https://www.fotosik.pl/zdjecie/e2b964f627146a43 , but I open this file in notepad and there are extra quotation marks.